# Get news posts into site

Tags: php, html, web

I would like to know if there is a way to get the most recent posts from a website including an image if the post has one.

for example get the last 20 bbc news business posts with images and display them on my website?

Comment: I believe you want something like RSS ? Do you want to implement it on your own ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You'll probably want an RSS reader library, a cron/schedule job to run an update every 10 minutes or so, a database to cache results, and a snippet of PHP to render the stories from the database. If you give it a solid go, people will give you suggestions on how to improve it, or how to proceed if you get stuck - but you do need to try it yourself first.

Comment: You can use Google Reader for a free, simple, and hosted widget.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Im pretty familiar with php and mysql, just never used RSS before. Ideally what i would like to do is, get the story, store it in a database and then retrieve it on the front end of my site, with the image. Is this possible with RSS?

Comment: Whether it is possible with RSS depends on the feed. A sample BBC one [is here](http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml), and as you can see it does not contain images. However in your cron job you could visit the news story URL itself and grab the primary image using an HTML parsing library.

Comment: Sounds good thanks, the theory sounds exactly what im after. However ive never written a cron job. Do you know of any good resources that i could have a look at?

Comment: A cron job is just a script that runs on the console instead of inside a web browser. It can be written in any language, including PHP. Do a web search for "PHP cron job", there are _millions_ of resources out there.

Comment: @user1364791 I added an example to my post on how to read and display a rss feed with simple pie.

Answer (score 1):

Find the url to the rss feed for the site then use take a look at the php feed library SimplePie.  It converts the feed at the url you give it to easy to an easy to use pho object format.

For your example, one of BBC England's new feeds is http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/england/rss.xml

First grab the simple pie library source: http://www.simplepie.org/downloads/

To consume this a feed in PHP and display it to the user do something like this:

```
 require_once('../simplepie.inc'); //explicitly include the SimplePie library

 $feed = new SimplePie(); //create your feed object
 $feed->set_feed_url('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/england/rss.xml'); //set the feed url to read
 $feed->init(); //Start consuming the feed!

 //the newly initialized feed object has some properties like it name, description, ect...
 echo "Feed Url ".$feed->get_permalink();  
 echo "Feed Title ".$feed->get_title(); 
 echo "Feed Description: ". $feed->get_description(); 

 $count = 0;

 //now, run though post of feeds, stop at 20
 foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item){ 
     if($count >= 20){
          break;
      }else{
          $count++;
      }
      echo "Link to original post: ".$item->get_permalink();
      echo "Title of Post: ". $item->get_title();
      echo "Description of the Post: ". $item->get_description();
      echo "Date Posted".$item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a');    
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Some websites have an API, a direct access to their contents, you can retreive it in the format XML or JSON.

You will have to use something like SimpleXML, DomXML, json_decode(); in PHP to cache the results in your database, or to query their API.